# reversed display of plots in beamer with tikz and visible

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have several curves to show and i want to present them in synchronisation with a bullet list on the same slide.

the list is good, but the different curves do not follow the order i want, even when I switch the orders.

How to proceed? Thanks a lot
Below the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% packages

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% customisations

\def \calR{\mathcal{R}}
\definecolor{grayTelecom}{RGB}{188,189,188}
\definecolor{redTelecom}{RGB}{191,18,56}

\mode<presentation>{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction: C-PPE and digital Dispersion Pre-Distortion (DPD)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.6]
    \begin{axis}[
        height          =   10cm,
        width           =   10cm,
        xlabel          =   {\Large $z$},
        ylabel          =   {\Large Correlation profiles~(a.u.)},
        xtick           =   {0,100,200,300,400,500},
        ymin            =   0.988,
        ymax            =   0.9942,
        x tick label style = {font = \Large},
        y tick label style = {font = \Large},
        y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/precision=4
        },
        legend style    =   {draw=none, legend columns = 2, legend pos = north west, font = \Large},
        legend entries  =   {$R$,$R^{(pd=5100)}$,$\calR$,$\calR^{(pd=5100)}$},
        ]
            {\visible<1->{
            \addplot [mark = none, color = gray] coordinates {
                    (0,                 0.9901)
                    (100,               0.9882)
                    (100,               0.9901)
                    (200,               0.9882)
                    (200,               0.9901)
                    (300,               0.9882)
                    (300,               0.9901)
                    (400,               0.9882)
                    (400,               0.9901)
                    (500,               0.9882)
                };}}
%            {\visible<1->{
%            addplot[
%                line width         = 2pt,
%                color          = black,
%                ]
%                table[x=d, y=PP17, col sep= comma]
%                {./Figures/PPE/PPE_17_5100_5spans.txt} ;}}
            {\visible<1->{
            \addplot [mark = *, mark size = 4pt, dashdotted, color = black] coordinates {
                    (7,                 0.99175)
                    (107,               0.99245)
                    (207,               0.99260)
                    (307,               0.99265)
                    (407,               0.99270)
                    };}}
            {\visible<1->{
            \addplot [mark = *, mark size = 4pt, dashdotted, color = black] coordinates {
                    (67,                0.99117)
                    (167,               0.99142)
                    (267,               0.99152)
                    (367,               0.99156)
                };}}
%            {\visible<2->{
%            \addplot[
%                line width         = 2pt,
%                color          = redTelecom!50!white,
%                ]
%                table[x=d, y=PP5100, col sep= comma]
%                {./Figures/PPE/PPE_17_5100_5spans.txt};}}
            {\visible<2->{
            \addplot [mark = pentagon*, mark size = 4pt, dashdotted, color = redTelecom] coordinates {
                    (7,                 0.98964)
                    (107,               0.98972)
                    (207,               0.98972)
                    (308,               0.98980)
                    (407,               0.98976)
                };}}
            {\visible<2->{
            \addplot [mark = pentagon*, mark size = 4pt, dashdotted, color = redTelecom] coordinates {
                    (67,                0.98858)
                    (167,               0.98865)
                    (267,               0.98868)
                    (368,               0.98865)
                };}}

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the `visible on=<...>` option from the `overlay-beamer-styles` tikz library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% packages

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% customisations

\def \calR{\mathcal{R}}
\definecolor{grayTelecom}{RGB}{188,189,188}
\definecolor{redTelecom}{RGB}{191,18,56}

\mode<presentation>{}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction: C-PPE and digital Dispersion Pre-Distortion (DPD)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.6]
    \begin{axis}[
        height          =   10cm,
        width           =   10cm,
        xlabel          =   {\Large $z$},
        ylabel          =   {\Large Correlation profiles~(a.u.)},
        xtick           =   {0,100,200,300,400,500},
        ymin            =   0.988,
        ymax            =   0.9942,
        x tick label style = {font = \Large},
        y tick label style = {font = \Large},
        y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/precision=4
        },
        legend style    =   {draw=none, legend columns = 2, legend pos = north west, font = \Large},
        ]
            
            \addplot [mark = none, color = gray,visible on=<2->] coordinates {
                    (0,                 0.9901)
                    (100,               0.9882)
                    (100,               0.9901)
                    (200,               0.9882)
                    (200,               0.9901)
                    (300,               0.9882)
                    (300,               0.9901)
                    (400,               0.9882)
                    (400,               0.9901)
                    (500,               0.9882)
                };
            \addlegendentry[visible on=<2->]{$R$}    
            \addplot [mark = *, mark size = 4pt, dashdotted, color = black,visible on=<1->] coordinates {
                    (7,                 0.99175)
                    (107,               0.99245)
                    (207,               0.99260)
                    (307,               0.99265)
                    (407,               0.99270)
                    };
            \addlegendentry{$R^{(pd=5100)}$}        
            \addplot [mark = *, mark size = 4pt, dashdotted, color = black,visible on=<1->] coordinates {
                    (67,                0.99117)
                    (167,               0.99142)
                    (267,               0.99152)
                    (367,               0.99156)
                };
            \addlegendentry{$\calR$}
            \addplot [mark = pentagon*, mark size = 4pt, dashdotted, color = redTelecom,visible on=<2->] coordinates {
                    (7,                 0.98964)
                    (107,               0.98972)
                    (207,               0.98972)
                    (308,               0.98980)
                    (407,               0.98976)
                };
            \addplot [mark = pentagon*, mark size = 4pt, dashdotted, color = redTelecom,visible on=<2->] coordinates {
                    (67,                0.98858)
                    (167,               0.98865)
                    (267,               0.98868)
                    (368,               0.98865)
                };
            \addlegendentry[visible on=<2->]{$\calR^{(pd=5100)}$}    
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much it is working ONLY if i change the compiler... I was compiling with pdfLaTeX while it is working with XeLaTeX from my side, what about yours?
Secondly, do you know a bit more about the details? why `\visible' or `visible on' behave differently? Thanks again!

Comment: It should work with all engines.

Comment: With `\visible`, the content is still present on all overlays. For text, beamer can change the opacity so you don't see the text, but this does not work with `\addplot`. You could use `\only` instead. This would mean that the plot is only present on the specified overlays. Personally, I think `visible on=<>` is easier to use in this case.

Comment: The disadvantage of `\only` is that the for plots in which you don't explicitly hard code the axis range, the scaling could change between overlays.

Comment: ok ok but with both methods, when i want to display sequentially the legend, i have errors: 

 legend entries  =   {\visible<1->{$R$},\visible<2->{$R^{(pd=5100)}$},\visible<1->{$\calR$},\visible<2->{$\calR^{(pd=5100)}$},\visible<1->{OTDR}},

More specifically the error is "You can't use `\lastskip' in restricted horizontal mode."

do you have any idea? thanks again

Comment: @louis see my edited answer - same trick as for the graphs

Comment: You are a genius, thx a ton!

Comment: @louis You're welcome!